# Is it bad to add "the" to domain name if the domain name is not avaliable? (Updated)

Tags: seo, domains, google-search-console, web-hosting, search

I am designing a website that is like an online magazine about a product and unfortunately `product.com` is not available and is parked however `theproduct.com` and `productmagazine.com` are available. Is it bad to purchase `theproduct.com`.

Also is there a way to remind people that the website is `theproduct.com` not product.com.

**Update:**

I just found out that the price of `product.com` is `$5,000` and product.net is available. Is it a good idea to get `product.net` and leave `theproduct.com` and `productmagazine.com`?

Comment: I personally would take product.net and set up a monitor on the .com in case it drops

Answer (score 2):

Of the two examples you provide, `theproduct.com` and `productmagazine.com`, only the second provides additional semantic value. For example, the word *the* has no semantic value for search whereas *magazine* would. Given that fact, `productmagazine.com` is the clear choice. While the use of the word *the* adds no value, it also causes no harm except that it may not be memorable and therefore users may not always include it. Something to consider. Keep in mind that domain names ***must*** be memorable and retain *top of mind* presence.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I thought that productmagazine.com is better too, but does the fact that `productmagazine.com` make the domain too long because my product is 9 letters long or is that no problem?

Comment: While a very long domain names are difficult to remember and type, I do not think your domain name would be too long. Also keep in mind, it is extremely rare that a user types a domain name anymore. Instead, they are following links and your domain name would be conceptually fine.

Comment: @closetnoc what about `productmagazine.com` vs `theproductmagazine.com`. If `productmagazine.com` is not available and have a established website.

Comment: @Roberthue With respect, get the *the* the hell outta there!! ;-) (How was that for fun??) It offers not value and can be confusing. Plus, unless your brand contains the word *the*, do not use that term or any term that is not part of your branding strategy. Otherwise your site will be branded poorly.

Comment: @closetnoc actually I wanted to buy `thelastsong.com` because `lastsong.com` was registered already. So I thought I could use the domain with `the`. But you are right, it will be branded poorly and may create confusion.

Comment: @Roberthue I guess the only time adding *the* makes sense is if it already is part of the brand. I am thinking of a few bars and restaurants as examples. In your case/example, the *the* is not bad if you are referring to "the last song" as in the logical sense.

Comment: @closetnoc Yes, it is in logical sense. One of my friend wants to create a website on the last perfect song you may want to hear before you ... (sleep/go to school/study/etc). And `lastsong.com` was already registered but it would have been a perfect fit for this. Since he is in brainstorming phase, he can modify brand name a little, that's not an issue. :)

Comment: @Roberthue I have often found that when you are not sure what to do about a domain name, think about it a little bit more, then stop for 1-2 weeks and something brilliant will come to mind. The key is to exhaust all your immediate thoughts, then flush the mind of anything domain name, forget about it, and let that one brilliant idea just appear on it's own. Do not try and make it happen, just let it happen.

Comment: Thanks. That's some good advice. :) I think we will try that.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative half decent .com domain is not the best option. I would definitely find a product. domain. There are now 800 different endings, and many of them will explain what your brand is about on the right side of the dot. You can see them all in this [infographic](http://blog.europeandomaincentre.com/infographic-know-domain-endings-com-whatever/). Maybe one of them is close to the product you sell or brand values you have.

Comment: Why is it not the best option though?

Comment: Because there is no naming convention for alternative .com domains. Some examples: getBRAND.com, BRANDteam.com, myBRAND.com. Yes, you can pick BRANDteam.com, and then see that BRAND.com and the other alternatives are owned by others. I really don't see the point, when you can get extensions, which describe your product better. The point I'm trying to make here is that .com is not the only TLD in the world, and it will lose it's importance, when we realise that domains should be meaningful on both sides of the dot. Your new brand of golf clubs should be found at BRAND.golf.

Comment: If you include your reasoning in your answer, it's more likely to help users and get upvoted :)

Comment: @AndrewLott, does choosing productmagazine.com mean that I have to publish a magazine?

Comment: @JackHill no, but I don't understand how that would help your case....

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is, and is bad for SEO too. Try to use it without "the".

Comment: You need to explain *why* this is true and cite sources if you have them. Otherwise this is just an unfounded opinion.

Comment: @JohnConde, is "the" really bad for SEO?